# Merge and replace two array elements

Tags: perl

How could I make it more simple?

```
@array= ('a','s','v','b','s','v','s','f','v');
$i= 0;
$maxarray= @array;
while ($i<$maxarray-1) {
    if (($array[$i] eq 's') && ($array[$i+1] eq 'v')) {
        splice (@array, $i, 1);
        $array[$i]= 'vs';
    } else { # if
        $i++;
    } # if
    $maxarray= @array;
} # while
```

output: (replace ('s', 'v') to ('vs')

Answer (score 3):

You can use `splice` to replace two elements in the middle of an array:

```
my $i = 0;
while ($i < $#array) {
    splice @array, $i, 2, 'vs'
        if 's' eq $array[$i] && 'v' eq $array[ $i + 1 ];
    $i++;
}
```

If you know the array can't contain a character (for example `!`) and that each element is just one character, you can `join` the array into a string and use the substitution to do the work:

```
my $str = join '!', @array;
$str =~ s/s!v/vs/g;
@array = split /!/, $str;
```

Comment: If each element is just one character, you don't need a delimiter at all.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Try it with `qw( a s v b v s c )`.

Comment: You are right, it splits between v and s. I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this another way completely using a string substitution

```
@array = split ' ', "@array" =~ s/s v/vs/gr;
```

#### output

```
a vs b vs s f v
```

Comment: @choroba: I've realised that my *other way completely* is a single-statement version of your second option. I apologise. I think it's best to leave it here now though.